# SSRS conditional grouping

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a dataset which contains different types of transactions, hours (resource/people), expenses, fees. There is already some grouping existing on project (projid), then trans type, then category. What I want to do is when the transtype is hours, group by resource, otherwise don't add any additional grouping. I tried adding this at the detail level group expression `=IIf(Fields!TransTableId.Value = 4559, Fields!Resource.Value, nothing)` however seems to be applying across the whole dataset. How do you add conditional grouping for just the rows you require? The group expression functionality is not behaving how I would expect... [image]

Comment: You can add a filter to the group based on the parameter values or data values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding a new group adjacent above within the tablix, setting filter to only include the data that I wanted, setup another filter on existing dataset to exclude data that's in the new group. This resolved my issue.  [image]